# Why is setting datagrid.Items.SortDescriptions(#).Direction giving an error?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I have a wpf datagrid that I want to sort programatically as if the user had clicked on the header. After some searching I found reference to using this:

```
datagrid_selected.Items.SortDescriptions(2).Direction = ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending
```

Looks like it would work. Intellisense says Direction is a getter and setter, but when I try to assign it to something I get the "Expression is a value and therefor cannot be the target of an assignment" error. By nature as a setter I should be able to assign this to a value, right? Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as if SortDescriptions are boxed values.

Instead, try the following.

```
var sortDescription = grid.Items.SortDescriptions[0];
sortDescription.Direction = System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending;
grid.Items.SortDescriptions[0] = sortDescription;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, a sortdescription is.. I forget the term for it, but once it has been assigned it cannot be reassigned, so it can't be done like that. sortDescription would have to be created as a new object. But this pointed me in the right direction, thanks!